# How to run Java code on Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, ide

I'm learning Java and using Eclipse as main IDE right now, but i can't run Java code from it (There are no Run as or Debug option in the Popup menu).

And personally, i don't to use 2 difference version of Eclipse.

[image]

Thanks

Edit : I'm using Eclipse Standard 4.3 and it doesn't have run as \ Java Application 's option. It only exists in Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.

Comment: Set the cursor inside your `public static void main` method and press Alt + Shift + X + J

Comment: Do you see that green color arrow below `Help` option in toolbar? That is the `run` button. Or press `ctrl+F11` to run the current main class.

Comment: And the little bug icon to the left of the run button is the debug button.

Comment: Also, there's a **Run** option in the menu bar. If you click it, you will see these two options **Run As** and **Run configurations...**

Comment: Everybody, this is Eclipse Juno, not Eclipse for Java. I don't even have the run as, debug option in the popup menu, and when i push the run button, it gave me an error 
"The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches"

Comment: @illunara I can see the **Run** option in the menu bar between the **Project** and **Window** options **in the posted image**. Check the menu bar below the title.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I'm Using Eclipse Standard 4.3, ok? It can't run Java Code without some config first.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is not the same version of Eclipse but the button is identical.

Comment: I personally dislike that button :) but yes it's a way to *execute* the current code.

Comment: What's not to like? I never really learned an alternative, so excuse me if that's a dumb question.

Comment: The shortcut is _probably_ preferrable. Developers are lazy and dont like that extra mechanical action required to use a mouse

Comment: I know all about that. So what is the shortcut? I see Luiggi mentioned above Alt+Shift+X+J which seems a little long for the function you will probably do the most in the entire program

Comment: Eclipse Juno is not setup for Java Development yet, that's why i can't run the code.

Comment: @illunara I don't see your point. Even Eclipse Modeling tools and the Eclipse for C/C++ developers (Juno version) allow me to create a simple Java project and execute it.

Comment: @illunara what do you mean by Juno is not setup for Java Development yet ?? I am using Juno almost a year now and I can run my applications..

Comment: @Gourabp : Maybe you using Eclipse Java?, i'm using Eclipse Standard. I had trouble when running C++ Code before too, have to make some change in project's Enviroment to make the code run

Comment: @illunara You have tagged your question under java,ide and I can see from the screen shot that you are trying to run a java class. TestClass.java  why don't you add C++ tag and make your question specific to running a C++ program ???

Comment: @Gourabp Yes, i am trying to run a Java Code, not C++. Same problem, but i don't know how to fix it to make Java code run yet.

Comment: @illunara  Please refer to my answer the EDIT section

Comment: @illunara you can update the JDT from help - > install new software or you can just put the plugins directly to the following location : eclipse-jee-juno-win32\eclipse\plugins\

Comment: @Gourabp: Thank a lots, i got it now :3 And sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

@illunara , I am using Juno since a long time now. You can run the program using one of the following way and it's pretty simple where is your confusion ??

1) refer to the following screen shot : You can right click on the java project you will see the run as option and from there you can choose on of the option to run as java application

2) You can go to run-> run as-> java application

3) you can right click the mouse on a java program and you can run from their too.

================================================================================================

## EDIT

Just as you mentioned you have eclipse standard so you need to add the JDT plugins before you do the above. you can find more details at the following site :

http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/overview.php

Hope this is helpful.

[image]
 [image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, you are using Eclipse JAVA, i'm using Eclipse Standard 4.3 now. That's make sense that's i can't run the Java code without some config first.

Comment: @illunara for your eclipse you need the JDT plug-ins that add the capabilities of a full-featured Java IDE to the Eclipse platform. You can find more details at the following url : http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/overview.php

Comment: Yes, before i post this question, i had take a look at older post in stackoverflow. Abd they said same thing . Can you go a little more detail on this please? How can i install this plugin?

Inside

Comment: I already mentioned in one of my comment please check that. by the way I was looking at the Juno standard bundle it already included the JDT. please refer : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr                                Can you check your plugin folder which should be located : under \plugins folder in the eclipse installation folder